# Django, extra argument for model field definition

Tags: django, arguments, field

I wanted to add extra argument to `model.Field` base class to
use later without defining field's extra options again in `Form` or `ModelForm` class.

And I can add extra argument with:

```
class Poll(models.Model):

    question = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                                extra= { 'widget': 'xw', 
                                         'admin_list_order': 3 })

    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

I can access extra arg with:

```
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from polls.models import Poll
>>> Poll._meta.fields[1].extra
{'widget': 'xw', 'admin_list_order': 3}
>>>
```

Is this an appropriate, Pythonic way to add an extra argument?

```
from django.db import models

# save old __init__ function of Field class
__oInit = models.Field.__init__

# define a new one to accept 'extra' arg
def __xinit__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    #chek if extra arg exist
    if kwargs.has_key('extra'):
        self.extra = kwargs.pop('extra')

    #call real __init__ 
    __oInit(self, *args, **kwargs)

# replace init with new one
models.Field.__init__ = __xinit__
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could break if they ever add an `extra` argument to a field. And *monkeypatches* are discouraged in general. You could go a safer route by adding a method to the `Field` base class:

```
def set_extra(self, **kwargs):
    self.extra = kwargs
    return self
models.Field.set_extra = set_extra
```

Then define your models like this:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200).set_extra(
            widget='xw', admin_list_order=3)
```

---

`has_key` is considered *unpythonic*, preferred way to check for key presence is:

```
if 'extra' in kwargs:
    self.extra = kwargs.pop('extra')
```

More *pythonic* would be just trying it and catching failure:

```
try:
    self.extra = kwargs.pop('extra')
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I got exactly what I asked for.<br> Also thanks for extra tip for the way checking extra arg.