# Django extend base Field Class

Tags: python, django, django-models

Basically, I want to add(patch in) a new *Field Option* as in here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#field-options to the base Field class, so it applies to all other fields

An optional parameter called 'js_inputmask' that is just a string that will be used by a javascript library, for example :

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    phone = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Phone Number', js_inputmask='(99) 9999-9999')
```

How can I add such? I've heard of monkey patch but not sure how to do it in constructors

Comment: Maybe have a look at django's source on github. `EmailField` is a good simple example to start with: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py#L517

Comment: @fips I'm not using forms nor do I plan to

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984083/django-extra-argument-for-model-field-definition) ?

Comment: BTW, it would be better to use special field to store phone numbers :)  https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field

Comment: @gaart I guess it's a matter of client vs server validation, the way I see it client seems more intuitive

Comment: @Mojimi Frontend validation is a first line of defense, it doesn't exclude backend validation and vice versa. Masked field is great, but why not to maximize restrictions and make sure there's no way to put invalid data into DB?