# Extending the `Field` class in Django

Tags: python, django

*All my searching gave results for "custom fields" in Django which is not what I'm after, I'm trying to customize the `Field` class. The only [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42794411/django-extend-base-field-class) was not answered.*

---

I'm building a form in Django, and I'm trying to specify a specific icon to appear by each input field. *([See mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSr5l.png))*

For example, I have added a non-standard `icon` argument when building my form:

`checkin.py`

```py
from django import forms

class CheckInForm(forms.Form):
    last_name = forms.CharField(
        icon="fa-id-card-o"
    )
    dob = forms.DateField(
        icon="fa-calendar"
    )
    ...
```

I would like to access this new `icon` argument from my template:

`checkin.html`

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {% for field in form %}
            <label for="{{ field.name }}" class="col-4 col-form-label">
                {{ field.label }}
            </label>
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <i class="fa {{ field.icon }}"></i>   <!--- icon argument --->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {{ field }}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="offset-4 col-8">
            <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Check In</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I run this code, it of course fails with:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'icon'

### Attempted approach

It seems to me this is a good case to [extend some Python classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526858/how-to-extend-a-class-in-python).

Both `CharField` and `DateField` are subclasses of Django's [`Field` class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#charfield), so I thought I could extend it with something like this:

```py
from django.forms import Field

class ExtendedField(Field):
    icon = ""
```

But this is where I get stuck: how do I deploy this new class? My `CheckInForm` object is a subclass of `forms.Form`, which is a subclass of `BaseForm`, which doesn't seem to directly create any `Field` objects -- so I'm not sure how they are related. However the `Field` class *is* used hundreds of times elsewhere. Should I override them all?

**tl;dr**: Is there an easier way to deploy this simple change to the `Field` class across every location it is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite dirty but straightforward solution:

```
from django import forms

class CustomCharField(forms.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *_, **kwargs):
        self.icon = kwargs.pop('icon', None)
        super().__init__(
            **kwargs
        )


class MyForm(forms.Form):
    title = CustomCharField(icon='dad', max_length=10)
```

In template get access by:

```
{{ form.title.field.icon}}
```

Comment: Thanks! How could I access it from inside the loop? Your example code works (calling the field name individually), however this is an empty result: `{% for field in form %} {{ field.icon }} {% endfor %}`

Comment: It's is in the example: {% for field in form %} {{ field.field.icon }} {% endfor %}

Comment: Thanks, your last comment fixed it! I upvoted you right away but I guess I don't have enough reputation yet to change visible scores. I appreciate your help!